# Changing ipv6 netmask and gateway on running interface

Tags: linux, networking, ipv6

I am trying to change the netmask and gateway of a running ipv6 interface.

On ipv4, I can simply do something like:

```
ifconfig eth0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gateway 123.123.123.123
```

How would I do this with ipv6?

I have tried several ways without any success:

```
ifconfig eth0 inet6 netmask 112 gateway xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::
```

How does the correct syntax look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ifconfig(8)` (provided by `net-tools`) has been obsoleted by `ip(8)` (in `iproute` or `iproute2`).

Some reasons to stop using `ifconfig` have been nicely summarized [here](http://inai.de/2008/0219-ifconfig-sucks.php).

For you use case, and according the `ip-address(8)` manpage, setting the netmask in [CIDR](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Range_blocks/IPv6#How_to_calculate_an_IPv6_CIDR_range) notation would be:

```
ip addr change xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::/112 dev eth0
```

And the `ip-route(8)` manpage describes how to set the default gateway:

```
ip -6 route add default via xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:: dev eth1
```

Comment: your line only ADDS an IP to an interface. It does not change the ip that has already been set. I wanted to just change the netmask of the existing IP.

Comment: You are right, I have corrected the command.