# OpenSuse: How to bring up the IPv6 stack after an "ifconfig eth0 down"

Tags: networking, opensuse, ifconfig

here is my config for eth0

`/etc/sysconfig/network/ifcfg-eth0`

```
BOOTPROTO='static'
BROADCAST=''
ETHTOOL_OPTIONS=''
IPADDR='5.1.0.2/24'
IPADDR_V6='5:1:0:1::2/64'
MTU=''
NAME='82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller'
NETMASK=''
NETWORK=''
REMOTE_IPADDR=''
STARTMODE='auto'
USERCONTROL='no'

suse64:/etc/sysconfig/network # ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:20:EE:6B:01  
          inet addr:5.1.0.2  Bcast:5.1.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: 5:1:0:1::2/64 Scope:Global
          inet6 addr: fe80::20ff:feee:6b01/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:96871 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:76100 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9308862 (8.8 Mb)  TX bytes:6519068 (6.2 Mb)
```

after a `ifconfig eth0 down`, then `ifconfig eth0 up`, the ipv6 address is not brought up. I have to to do a `rcnetwork restart` to get it up.

```
suse64:/etc/sysconfig/network # ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 02:00:20:EE:6B:01  
          inet addr:5.1.0.2  Bcast:5.1.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20ff:feee:6b01/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:96846 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:76066 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:9306424 (8.8 Mb)  TX bytes:6516032 (6.2 Mb)
```

Why and how can I bring the v6 stack up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing ipv6 netmask and gateway on running interface](http://serverfault.com/questions/528362/changing-ipv6-netmask-and-gateway-on-running-interface)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use inet6 parameter:

```
ifconfig eth0 inet6 up
```

But **ifconfig** is obsolete. The **ip** command has more features incl. VLANs (802.1Q) and works better.

```
ip link set dev eth0 down
ip link set dev eth0 up
ip address show
```

Explicitly for IPv6 protocol:

```
ip -6 link set dev eth0 down
ip -6 link set dev eth0 up
ip ad sh
ip -6 ad sh
```

Maybe the IPv6 is not correctly enabled. 
Start yast as a su or sudo, then follow these menu items:

--> Network Devices

--> Network Settings

--> Alt+G (Global options)

--> Alt+E (Enable IPv6) in "IPv6 Protocol Settings" section
The checkbox must be checked on.

--> OK

reboot

Answer (score 0):

ifup / ifdown will read the interface files